# Achartengine Line Graph Using Data from JSON parsing

Tags: json, achartengine

I am parsing a JSON link in order to get 2 string series(the dates in the x axis and integers in the y axis).
I think I need to convert both strings to integers, I am not sure.
I want to display the dates in the x axis and the values in the y axis using a graph line from achartengine library.

String serie from JSON "formatted":
"54.5x"
"28.8x"
"80.7x".......

String serie from JSON "enddates":
"2011-12-31"
"2010-10-19"
"2009-10-113".......

The 2 string series are "formatted" and "enddates"
How do I display formatted in the y axis and dates in the x axis using achartengine line graph? Below is a line graph example with achartengine that I could modify. Thank you in advance.

```
public class LineGraph{



public Intent getIntent(Context context) {



    // Our first data
    int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }; // x values!
    int[] y =  { 30, 34, 45, 57, 77, 89, 100, 111 ,123 ,145 }; // y values!
    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries("Line1");//That's the description of the line at the bottom
    for( int i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
    {
        series.add(x[i], y[i]);
    }



    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();//This object holds all the series(lines) in one graph
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    //each series has a renderer

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // This will be used to customize line 1
    // Customization time for line 1!
    renderer.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);
    renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);// it displays the y values right by the chart dots



    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); // Holds a collection of XYSeriesRenderer and customizes the graph
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
    mRenderer.setYLabels(10);
    mRenderer.setXLabels(5); //sets x values on the x axis, for instance if x=5, it sets 5 values in total on the x axis
    mRenderer.setChartTitle("Bus Vs Taxy Chart");
    mRenderer.setXTitle("Dates");
    mRenderer.setYTitle("Number of Vehicles Sold");





    //the intent puts together the Context(context), the Dataset(dataset), the Renderer(mRenderer) and the Line Graph Title
    //The LineChartIntent specifies the type of chart that I want, in this case a line.
    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, mRenderer, "Line Graph");//here I set the Title
    return intent;

}
```

}